# integers which are sums of binomial coefficients: $\sum_i {n \choose k_i}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, additive-combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Let $n$ be an integer. For $S$ a subset of $\{0,\dots,n\}$, define
$$m(S) = \sum_{k \in S} {n \choose k}.$$
Let $M_n$ be the set of integers of the form $m(S)$ for all sets $S \subset \{0,\dots,n\}$. Obviously $M_n \subset \{0,\dots,2^n\}$ and for $n=1,2,3$ this inclusion is an equality. For $n \geq 4$ however, this inclusion is not an equality, as for instance $n-1$ is not in $M_n$.

> What can be said about $M_n$? Is there a simple way to recognize if a number less than $2^n$ is in $M_n$? Can we compute or estimate the proportion $|M_n|/(2^n+1)$ of elements of $\{0,\dots,2^n\}$ that are in $M_n$?

I ask this question mainly out of curiosity, but elements of the form $m(S)$ appeared recently in paper I am working on.

Comment: PS: I was not so sure about the tags for this question.  Please feel free to edit...

Comment: Since the binomial coefficients appear in pairs $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$, your question can be reworded as asking for the number of distinct sums of the form $\sum_{k=0}^{n/2} a_k \binom{n}{k}$ with $a_k=0, 1, 2$.  Thus there are at most $3^{n/2}$ possibilities.  My first guess would be that maybe roughly the right order (that is, $\sqrt{3}^{n+o(n)}$ may be the right number).  Certainly $M_n$ grows exponentially, as the binomial coefficients initially grow rapidly allowing for few repetitions in sums (such sets are called disassociated).

Comment: Since ${p\choose k}$ is divisible by $p$ for $p$ prime and $k\not=0,p$, the set $M_p$ contains only integers congruent to $0,1,2$ modulo $p$ if $n=p$ is a prime number. This argument can be slightly generalized.

Comment: One should also mention m in M_n iff 2^n - m is.

Comment: Also adjacent coefficients have a ratio greater than 2 when 3k less than n, so at least 3^{n/3 - something small} numbers can be represented for large n.

Comment: Indeed, some simple counting should get at least 18^{n/6} elements of M_n.

Comment: For reference: the first 10 values of $\lvert M_n\rvert-1$ beginning with $n=1$ are $1,2,4,8,14,20,44,56,116,242,394$. This sequence (or $\lvert M_n\rvert$ itself) is not in OEIS.

Comment: @Thomas: do you mean "beginning with $n=0$"?

Comment: Yes, of course, sorry.

Comment: @Thomas, it's not in oeis because you decided to subtract 1. If you allow the empty sum, and put that 1 back in there, you get https://oeis.org/A205536 --- but there is little information there, beyond the tabulation up to $n=29$. There is also a link to the related https://oeis.org/A205542

Comment: Curiously the sequence seems correct for what we want but  the description given says that it is the counts where each binomial coefficient (including the central one for even $n$) can be used 0,1 or 2 times. So one could have $\binom{n}{2}$ and also $\binom{n}{n-2}$ used twice each. I wrote to the author.

Answer (score 3):

As Gerry notes, it is in the OEIS if we also allow the empty sum of $0$. As I commented, the description does seem a bit off.

The counts (out to $n=30$) do indeed seem to be close to the upper bound of  $3^{(n+1)/2}$ (for odd $n$) or $2\ 3^{(n-2)/2}$ (for $n$ even). The bound is obtained for $n=9$ and seldom goes much below half of that. The counts $M_n$ for $n=18,19,20$ are $21345, 22005, 64917$ so ratios of 1.0309 and then 2.95. In general prime $n$ results in a relatively small increase although $n=19$ is much more dramatic than $23$ or $29.$ In that case of $n=19$ we have only about $30\%$ of the upper bound.

The counts are always odd (including $1$ for $n=0$) with the exception $M_1=2$. This is because (as observed) the attainable values come in pairs $m,2^n-m$ except that the attainable value $2^{n-1}$ is unpaired. ($n=0,1$ are special)

The values mod $3$  are

$2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1$

I suppose the high number of multiples of $3$ can be explained by the observation that if we can attain a sum of $m$ without making use of $\binom{n}{1}$ or $\binom{n}{n-1}$ then we can also obtain $m+1$ and $m+2$. Often the values $m$ of the first type are spread out enough that distinct values are more than $2$ apart (for example when $n \gt 2$ is prime and all these sums are multiples of $n$). An exception is $n=10.$ There we have $250=\binom{10}{1}+\binom{10}{3}+\binom{10}{7}$ and $252=\binom{10}{5}$ among others.